# Azure Durable Functions - HTTP Starter Install

Tags: azure, npm, kudu, azure-durable-functions

I have been following the Microsoft azure developers online course and i have started an exercise on durable functions

First thing i had to do was to use Kudu to install the durable functions package via a package.json file

all details are in this link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-create-portal

After this i had to create a new HTTP start function (details also in the above link) but the install does not complete successfully (see attached screen shot)

I have tried this a few times and no joy and unable to continue the course until i get this resolved

screen shot shows the errors and no matter how long i leave it it never completes
have also tried restarting the function and try again but no luck

[screen shot - error installing HTTP start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRepT.png)

Answer (score 0):

ok i have now overcome this

Details of the fix are in this link
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Updating-your-function-app-extensions

its important to stop the function otherwise you don't see the bin folder and the .csproj file you need to edit

Comment: Same issue for me but even with the function stopped I don't see the bin folder